# Visual Studio cannot enter "grater than" character

Tags: visual-studio

I have now problem at home, when I wish to enter "greater than (>)" by <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in last version of Visual Studio, it doesn't do anything. I don't know what is this for feature, but I'm not able to solve that problem. In OS out of VS it works normally - like here - >>>. Interesting is that "<" symbol (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) works normally. Here (at home) I have fresh installation without any custom settings, in work, I have same installation but installed before some time, without any custom settings too, but in work it works normally.

Comment: See if your keyboard language change when VS has the focus.

Comment: No, it doesn't change, this works fine. But in Visual Studio is setted keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+. for "EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.QuickActionsForPosition" and I really don't know how to disable it, there is no button for release that shortcut by VS.

Comment: Go to options/keyboard, search for the name of the command and press the "remove" button when the shortcut shows.

Comment: OMG, that works... Why it cannot allow to remove that directly after pressing shortcut inside "Press shortcut keys:" textbox. Why to do it easy, if it can be difficult. Thank you :-)

Comment: Why do you want to use *that* combination instead of the default Shift + '.' ?

Comment: Because I'm not using standard English keyboard and I know many key shortcuts for many years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank to Joachim Isaksson

1) Check where is shortcut used
[image: 1st Check where is shortcut used]

2) Manually search for that command
[image: 2nd manually search for that command]

3) Now its removable
[image: 3rd now it allows to be removed]